# Passing multiple values to a parameter for a Fiddler POST request

Tags: post, fiddler

I am trying to pass multiple values for a parameter in a POST request body as follows

var1=1&var2=2&var34=3,4&var5=5

I've tried several ways to pass var34 as a string of values 3 and 4 but still not working.  Need some help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: what is your Content-Type of request?

Comment: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a question about Fiddler, so it's not clear what you're asking specifically.

The server interprets POST data according to its own rules, and there's no standard for handling duplicate name/values in urlencoded data.

Some servers would accept `var1=1&var2=2&var34=3,4&var5=5` as you've used, while some would prefer `var1=1&var2=2&var34=3&var34=4&var5=5`.

What error or problem are you encountering?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's the server (I use R) side that I need to adjust the codes to accommodate the POST request.  It has nothing to do with the request.  Thank you so much for the suggestion!